# Searching Mysql database containing expression like 1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search, match-against

I'm new here. I have only basic knowledge of PHP and Mysql.

I have a math expression like:

> [1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 9<sup>2</sup> -
>   x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>]

which is stored in MySQL database as:

```
[1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 9<sup>2</sup> - x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>].
```

I want to search that column from MySQL database using the input string `$str='1^3 + 2^4 + 9^2 - x_1x_2';`. The MySQL column is set as a full-text index so I need to search it using MATCH AGAINST method.

**UPDATE**: I added the relevant code from my application below.

My question is why the MySQL query returning 0. if I even change the input string the same thing is happening. Like

```
$str=$_GET['search']; //$_GET['search'] is equal to '1<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>4</sup> + 9<sup>2</sup> - x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>'
//the $str contain the search string
$query = "(Select col1,col2,MATCH (col3) AGAINST ('".$str."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance from table_name WHERE MATCH (col3) AGAINST ('".$str."' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE))";
$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 $foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($run);
//$foundnum returning  0
```

Comment: Pls ask a question, do not just simply describe your task! Pls include what you have tried because SO is not a free coding service to code a solution for a task from scratch for you. Pls do not ask multipke questions in one post, not matter how related you think those are!

Comment: @Shadow SORRY AS I TOLD I'M NEW HERE AND THIS WAS MY FIRST QUESTION. I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for an exact match for your search string, then you do not need fulltext search, just a simple matching. Also, pls do not shout in your comments (all capital letters=shouting), it is impolite! I gave you the relevant pointers to improve your question!

Comment: Full text indexing is specifically designed for natural language, which is the opposite of what you have. The quick solution would be a quick and dirty search and replace on `$str` to match database format. The correct solution would be a full expression parser to convert either formats to a normalised representation. Perhaps we could use some extra context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the string `1^3` is not the same as `1<sup>3</sup>`, there is no SQL method to have them match.  Also, there is no simple amount of PHP code to declare that they are the same.

You need to come up with a canonical form for "power" and use it in both the data in the table and the search string.  Probably you should pick the "math" representation for searching `1^3`.  You *could* use a second column for the HTML representation `1<sup>3</sup>`.

But, there is another problem.  `FULLTEXT` indexing works with "words" separated by spacing and punctuation.  So the words in those are `1`, `3`, and `sup`.

Still more trouble...  `FULLTEXT` defaults to a minimum of 3 letters for a "word".  So `sup` would be the only "word".

So, what to do?  If you can decide on a canonical form, then see `=`, `LIKE`, or `REGEXP` for string comparisons, not `FULLTEXT`.